# Lost DVI output

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop

I have tried to install the OpenRazer software for a keyboard in Linux Mint Mate, it worked well but after a reboot my secondary monitor connected with DVI port is not working anymore. I did not install anything else or change any setting in between.

If I disconnect the main monitor the BIOS loading screen starts the secondary monitor fine, but when the system boots it starts flashing the `No DVI signal` message. It gets signal and loses it again.

I checked `lshw -c display` and I got the following:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 430]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I changed cables, tried to switch to Nouveau display driver but none of them helped.

I have deleted the config file with `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml` and rebooted the system and nothing happened.

I have tried `xrandr -s 0` but it did not solved the issue

Comment: Maybe faulty cables.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but when I tried a different one the problem remained. For sure I checked that cabel with a different pc and it worked with that one well.

Comment: Since the issue seemed to be a problem with the cables and not software, I am closing this as non-reproducible as it is very specific to your situation.

Comment: I assumed it is not a hardware problem because it happened after a software installation, but yes I was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my problem: I switched the vga and dvi cables in the monitors, the primary is connected with vga and secondary is with dvi, (since this is an office machine connecting the primary monitor this way is not a problem), on the gpu side of the cables of course there is no change.

My secondary monitor started working immediately after the change, I did not needed to reboot.